# problem involving bits operation in C language

Tags: c

```
return (b & 0x20) ? b | ~0x3F : b & 0x3F;
```

is there is anyways to write this function with if and else or any other statement.
I have tried this one down but it didn't work.

```
if (return (b & 32)) {
    b | ~63;
} else {
    b & 63;
}
}
```

Comment: The original `return` is clean to me.. any particular reason you want to rewrite it? Just not comfortable with that syntax?

Comment: I'd add few parentheses though. The precedence might be not that obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You just put your `return` in the wrong place.  Try this:

```c
if (b & 0x20) {
  return b | ~0x3F;
}
else {
  return b & 0x3F;
}
```

I don't think C lets you return from the middle of of an `if` condition, and even if it did, that would not match the behavior of your original line of code because you would be returning the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (b & 0x20)
{
  return b | ~0x3F;
}
// else implied
return b & 0x3F;
```

Some coding standards don't like multiple `return` statements.  Another option is

```
if (b & 0x20)
{
  b |= ~0x3F;
}
else
{
  b &= 0x3F;
}
return b;
```

However, this is different logic since the value of `b` is actually changing.  If it's a local, no problems.  Otherwise, there might be further reaching ramifications.